# Redirect with an exception

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

I think this is easy but I am afraid I cannot solve this all by myself.

I have moved a website to another domain, and I've set up some permanent redirections. However, I'd like to **preserve one URL** from any rewrite. Right now my configuration is like this:

```
Redirect permanent /olduser/exception/ ???
Redirect permanent /olduser/dir/ http://newuser.domain.com/a.html
Redirect permanent /olduser/other/ http://newuser.domain.com/q.html
Redirect permanent /olduser/other/sub/ http://newuser.domain.com/t/some.html
Redirect permanent /olduser/ http://newuser.domain.com/
```

Of course the first line is problematic, since I am redirecting in the last line the whole subdirectory to the new domain. On the new domain **I don't have privileges**, as it is a static website similar to GitHub.

Note that I cannot simply use a rewrite rule, as the old directories don't correspond to new files/dirs. Or better, *I cannot see* how I can do this :)

How can I make the `/olduser/exception/` work on the old server, without affecting the other rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/olduser/(?!exception/).* http://newuser.domain.com/
```

Instead of:

```
Redirect permanent /olduser/ http://newuser.domain.com/
```

Will redirect all `/olduser` request exept pattern matching `/olduser/exception/` to your new domain.